# What permissions are needed for Register-ScheduledTask?

Tags: windows, powershell, task-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script that runs under its own user account for security purposes. It needs to be able to schedule tasks as part of its operation, and uses the `ScheduledTasks` module to do so. After seeing [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784311/permissions-required-to-create-modify-tasks-in-windows-task-scheduler), I granted the script's account Full Control over `%SystemRoot%\System32\Tasks`, but `Register-ScheduledTask` still fails with "Access is denied." I have allowed the script's account to log on as a batch job and as a service.

What permissions/configuration changes are needed to make this work right?

Comment: Provide an example set of commands that fails.

Comment: In trying to reduce the set of commands that triggers an error, I found the cause of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that the problem was due to me specifying `-RunLevel Highest`. Apparently you can't do that with a restricted account. Removing that parameter allows it to work.